# to install npm bluetooth-hci-socket in project repository

Tags: node.js

all I'm going to develop a BLE Desktop app by using node, Electron Js as well as bleno. for this, we need "npm bluetooth-hci-socket" but I am facing some issues to installing this npm library into my project repo.

Comment: Please share those issues here

Comment: make: *** [binding.target.mk:109: Release/obj.target/binding/src/BluetoothHciSocket.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/rahul/SmartPlugBLEDesktop/bleno/node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

Comment: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/rahul/SmartPlugBLEDesktop/bleno/node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Please include those errors into the text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Install node version manager:
sudo npm install -g n

Downgrade node to v 8.9.0 by:
sudo n 8.9.0

and
sudo npm install bluetooth-hci-socket --unsafe-perm

Comment: NOT working on my raspberry pi 3b.
Failed at the bluetooth-hci-socket@0.5.1 install script.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `install` verb in your command. It should be:

`npm install bluetooth-hci-socket`

Comment: No @Delapouite I'am using 'install' as well

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm install bluetooth-hci-socket2
```

If you are using bleno, you can directly execute:

```bash
npm install bleno2
```

Hope it helps you